# In Lotus Notes, Create a View with only Send & Inbox mails

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-formula

I want to create a view in lotus Notes 8.5 with only mails in Send (view) and inbox (folder).

I try to custom formula

```
SELECT ( @IsNotMember("A"; ExcludeFromView) & IsMailStationery != 1 & 
Form != "Group" & Form != "Person" ) & 
!( DeliveredDate = "" & PostedDate != "" & !(@IsMember("S"; ExcludeFromView)) )
```

from [Lotus Notes custom view received mail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14757667/lotus-notes-custom-view-received-mail)
or 
[How to Identify the Document is in Inbox/Draft/Sent in Lotus Notes Using Notes API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9802996/how-to-identify-the-document-is-in-inbox-draft-sent-in-lotus-notes-using-notes-a)
and integrate @WhichFolders but without success.

Comment: You cannot query a folder's index while building a view index. The only way to do this is with an agent or plug-in that maintains an item in the messages themselves, setting it when the message is added to the Inbox and unsetting it when it is moved out.

Comment: Had a similar question which had a good answer:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24329560/lotus-notes-is-it-possible-to-create-a-view-that-excludes-documents-in-all-fold